# How to use method stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error

Tags: iphone

I don't know how to use this method.

I want to get the data in an rtf file as a NSString, however I can not.

Here is part of my code.

```
NSString *filePath = @"path of the file";

NSString *ImagePath = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];

imagePath = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath encoding:(NSStringEncoding)nil error:(NSError**) nil];
```

I can't readout the data in that .rtf file. I am appreciate that everyone may help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this
`imagePath = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil`];

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function

```
NSString *content = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath
                                                 usedEncoding:nil
                                                        error:nil] autorelease];
```

before using this be sure u giving a right path (**filepath**) to the string.

Comment: how long ur file and is ur path is true?

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer. I still can't work it out. I save my test.rtf file at path /Users/ABC/Desktop/test.rtf  and the content in this test.rtf file is /Users/ABC/Desktop/test.jpg  I want to load a photo through test.rtf file.  Is anything wrong with my contents in my test.rtf file?